# CURL to access TPLink router

Tags: curl

I try to access TPLink "Archer A10" router using the cURL command to read the connection status.
Using the Browser inspect element/Network to capture commands to do GET/POST and save as cURL.
But it fails in POST command.

Anyone have any ideas or examples ?

Comment: What is your cURL command... and error message ? (remember: replace user, password and token by explicit keywords)

Comment: After checking the Browser, it is using RSA (256 bytes) for login.  Does cURL able to support ?